# The central limit theorem from a path integral?

Tags: path-integral, statistics

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation it is noted that the central limit theorem can be interpreted as the first
historical evaluation of a statistical path integral. Is this true? Can someone show how one would derive the central limit theorem using a path integral?

Comment: How is this a physics question?

Comment: I agree it is not really a physics question. But it seems to me that in general  physicists know much more about functional integration and path integrals than mathematicians, so I though I ask the question here.

Comment: I think you would have to dig in rather deep there. The problem with Feynman's path integrals is that, in a strict treatment, they don't converge properly and the results of the naive limit depends on the choice of sampling. For anything else than midpoint sampling on each individual interval they seem to be producing unphysical terms, if I remember correctly. Physicists don't care about that because we rarely ever calculate path integrals directly, but the mathematicians had to do a lot of work to make the concept even palatable.